# Using editcap from specific wireshark version

Tags: wireshark, pcap, editcap

I currently have Wireshark 2.6.8 and 3.0.2 installed on Ubuntu 18.04, and I would like to be able to use editcap as included in the 3.0.2 installation to modify pcap files.

However, every time I run editcap (a simple editcap -h to verify the build that I am using) from the terminal, it shows that I am running it from Editcap (Wireshark) 2.6.8 (Git v2.6.8 packaged as 2.6.8-1~ubuntu18.04.0)

Is there a way to change this without removing Wireshark 2?

Comment: it might be helpful to know that i installed 2.6.8 from a mirror using apt-get, and the 3.0.2 was built from source. I was able to run 

WIRESHARK_RUN_FROM_BUILD_DIRECTORY=1 ./run/editcap <options>

and this worked.

Comment: What does the command `which editcap` print?

And did you install Wireshark 3.0.2 by running `make install` after building Wireshark from source?  If so, is there a `/usr/local/bin/editcap` file?

Comment: which editcap returns /usr/bin/editcap. I did, though there is no usr/local/bin/editcap file; only in usr/bin/editcap. I'm not sure if it's a path issue, but the fact that i have to select WIRESHARK_RUN_FROM_BUILD_DIRECTORY=1 is a little bit telling; not sure how to fix it though

Comment: > which editcap returns /usr/bin/editcap

Answer (score 0):

> there is no usr/local/bin/editcap file

Then the *only* version of Wireshark you have installed appears to be the 2.6.8 version.

> the 3.0.2 was built from source

You may have *built* the 3.0.2 version from source, but, unless you ran "make install" (or "ninja install" if you used Ninja rather than make), you haven't *installed* it.  You may have to run that as root.

Once you've *installed* the version you built from source, there should be a `/usr/local/bin/editcap` (unless you've explicitly configured the build to install somewhere other than the default location).

Comment: >>>(unless you've explicitly configured the build to install somewhere other than the default location)

I did, under the impression that i would be able to maintain backward compatibility for some of scripts that depended on commands found in tshark 2.6.8

Comment: Then you will either need to make sure that the `bin` directory of the install location is in your `$PATH` - for example, if you installed under `/opt`, the `bin` directory would be `/opt/bin` - or will need to explicitly give the full path to the version of `editcap` in that directory (`/opt/bin/editcap` in the example).  Adding the install directory's `bin` directory to `$PATH` runs the risk of breaking scripts, if they run a command and get the installed-from-source version rather than the installed-from-APT version.